# Surface normal vs tangent space

Tags: lighting, normal-mapping, bump-map

I am having a hard time being convinced why calculating the tangent space the way most textbooks do is the best thing to do? Why shouldn't we just simply use the edges of our triangle as Tangent and BiTangent and use their cross product as the normal and use the resulting matrix in bump mapping. These two approach give the same result but what I have described is arguably far more intuitive?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind the reason why tangent space is used. It's to provide an orientation for the normal map to know whether the normal needs to be adjusted in the u or v direction.

For that you need to know which way the u and v axis point at the fragment you are computing and *it needs to be consistent across multiple triangles*.

Also you have 6 ways to pick the edge pairs of a triangle (3 if you fix winding order), how would you know in the fragment shader which way was picked.